# Discrete time homogeneous Markov chain

Tags: probability, markov-chains, transition-matrix

Consider  a system with a two components. We observe the state of the system every hour. A given component operating at time $n$ has probability $p$ of failing before the next observation at time $n + 1$. A component that was in failed condition at time $n$ has a probability $r$ of being repaired by time $n+1$,independent of how long the component has been in a failed state. The component failures and repairs are mutually independent events. Let $X_n$ be the number of components in operation at time n. The process $(X_n, n=0,1,...)$ is a discrete time homogeneous Markov chain with state space $I= 0,1,2.$

a) I want to determine its transition matrix, draw  a state diagram
and 
b) Obtain the steady state probability vector, if it exists.

Solutions: I am not understanding what are the component's state here? first one is operating component state and second one is failing component state. What is the third one?  and what is meant by "mutually independent events"? Does it have same meaning as "mutually exclusive events" have?

Would any one  answer these questions a) and b)?

Comment: The state space is the number of components currently functioning, out of a total of (apparently) 2 components. "Mutually independent" is a bit redundant, it just means that each failure event and each repair event are independent, as is required for the Markov property.

Comment: @Ian, State space is given$I=0,1,2$ Now what state '0' is? what state '1' is? and lastly what 'state '2' is?

Comment: 0 means none of them are working. 1 means 1 of the two of them are working. 2 means both of them are working.

Comment: State $0$ is when both components are broken, state $1$ is when one component is in operation, and state $2$ is when both components are in operation.  The two components need not be distinguished in this model.  That's why you just count the number of operating components.  Note that $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive if $P(A \cap B) = 0$, whereas they are independent if $P(A \cap B) = P(A) \cdot P(B)$.  So $A$ and $B$ are both exclusive and independent only if at least one of $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ is $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a)The transition probability matrix is :

$\begin{pmatrix}(1-r)^2 & 2r(1-r) & r^2 \\
                              p(1-r) & pr +(1-p)(1-r)  & r(1-p) \\
                         p^2 & 2p(1-p) & (1-p)^2\end{pmatrix}$

b) The steady-state probabilities are $\pi_0=[p/(p+r)^2]$

$\pi_1=[2[r/(p+r)][p/(p+r)]$

$\pi_2=[r/(p+r)^2]$